# Фабрика синглтон

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется класс - простая фабрика, в котором реализован статический метод, который генерирует инстанс одного объекта на основе принятого в параметрах другого объекта. Данный метод может вызываться с разных потоков. Нужно ли делать данную фабрику синглтоном? Если да, то зачем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Одиночка (англ. Singleton) — порождающий шаблон проектирования,
>   гарантирующий, что в однопроцессном приложении будет единственный
>   экземпляр некоторого класса, и предоставляющий глобальную точку
>   доступа к этому экземпляру.

[Источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Чисто из определения - **нет**, не нужно использовать синглтон.

Паттер "синглтон" предполагает, что будет существовать единственный экземпляр данного класса. Но задайте себе вопрос: а нужен ли вам этот экземпляр?

> Имеется класс - простая фабрика, в котором реализован статический
>   метод, который генерирует инстанс одного объекта на основе принятого в
>   параметрах другого объекта.

Предполагая, что этот статический метод является в классе единственным, то нет необходимости вообще иметь возможность порождать объекты данного класса. Вместо этого можно обойтись простой функцией-фабрикой.

```
class Fabric {
    static generate(template) {
        // ...
    }
}

Fabric.generate(instance);

// думаю, можно безболезненно превратить в это:

function generate(template) {
    // тот же код, что и в Fabric.generate();
}

generate(instance);
```

Более того, статический метод по определению не может быть вызван на экземпляре класса, поэтому нет абсолютно никакой необходимости в наличии даже единственного экземпляра этого класса, ведь фабричный метод можно вызвать на самом классе (более того, только на нем, поскольку он является статическим).

Поэтому на вашем месте я бы однозначно не стал реализовывать синглтон, а более того, рассмотрел бы возможность избавления от класса вообще.

Comment: На самом деле класс фабрики содержит множество статических методов (для примера указал только один), поэтому реализован отдельный класс. Спасибо!

Comment: @user287120 суть в том, что если он не содержит *не*статических, то и экземпляр такого класса вам вряд ли нужен.

Answer (score 2):

Неплохо было бы, конечно, указать язык, на котором вы пишите. Но скажу в рамках PHP. Скажу прямо, редко видел фабрики со статичными методами, но да не в том вопрос. Смысла делать фабрику синглотом лично я по описанному применению не вижу по той простой причине, что статичный метод принадлежит классу, а не объекту. Т.е. он по своей природе существует в единственном экземпляре.

Comment: В данном случае Java. А что может мешать сделать методы статическими, если глобальные переменные не используются и поэтому потокобезопасность присутствует? Вроде принципы фабрики не нарушаю или как?